# Need the expected output from Hive/SQL query

Tags: hive, hiveql

Input:

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
```

Expected Output:

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
.
.
..
.
```

Need to find the Hive /SQL query for the expected output like this

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query, have used CTE with 3 records as my input.

```
hive> with t1 as (select 1 as col1 union select 2 as col1 union select 3 as col1) select t11.col1 from t1 as t11,t1 as t12 where t11.col1>=t12.col1;
```

Comment: My requirement is for N records.

Comment: It was an example, you query would be select t11.col1 from <tablename> as t11, <tablename> as t12 where t11.col1>=t12.col1;